# Accessing a nested div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I define a `tabs` using `JQuery`

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <table>
      <tr><td>demo</td></tr>
    </table>        
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <table>
      <tr><td>demo</td></tr>
      <div id="hello">
        <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
      </div>
    </table> 
  </div>
```

I can hide `tabs-1` with the simple code

```
function hideTabs1() {
   $("#tabs-1").hide(); 
}
```

How can I hide just the words "Hello World"?

Comment: You cannot have a div between table rows like that, it's invalid HTML.

Comment: Your markup is not valid. A `<div>` element is no valid child of a `<table>`!

Comment: Thank you.  So if I want to hide a number of elements of a table, but not all, then I would need to hide each one individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is a combination of a few people's answers.
(I am not sure what SO protocol is for this, so I answered my own question, and marked-up all the other answers)

Once I realized that a DIV can not be a child of a TABLE (thank you bfavaretto and Sirko) then I realized I could divide the table into two tables, and give the table I wanted to hide an ID (using Ruben's and Ryan's idea for a `td`) and then just hide this table.

Thank you everybody.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement!

Answer (score 2):

try this one :

```
$("#hello td").hide();
```

or better :

```
$("#tabs-2 td:eq(1)").hide();
```

Comment: That probably won't select any element since the browser will correct the HTML/DOM. For example, Chrome moves the `div` *before* the table.

Comment: @FelixKling what about `$("#tabs-2 td:eq(1)").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#hello td').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#hello').css('display', 'none');


<div id="tabs-2">
    <table>
      <tr><td>demo</td></tr>
       <tr  id="hello"><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    </table> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For simplicity, I only put one "Hello World" inside my inner DIV in my question, but in reality I have many table entries there. So I guess I could use your solution and access each table entry independently to hide it (without using DIV - I didn't realize that one can't have a DIV inside a TABLE.)

Answer (score 1):

You should really fix the HTML to something like this so that it's valid:

```
...
<div id="tabs-2">
   <table>
      <tr><td>demo</td></tr>
      <tr id="hello"><td>
         Hello World
      </td></tr>
   </table> 
</div>
...
```

Then your would be jQuery:

```
$("#hello td").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For simplicity, I only put one "Hello World" inside my inner DIV in my question, but in reality I have many table entries there. So I guess I could use your solution and access each table entry independently to hide it (without using DIV - I didn't realize that one can't have a DIV inside a TABLE.) –

Comment: You can have a `div` inside of a table, but it needs to be a child of `td` rather than a child of `table`. IE. `<table><tr><td><div>...`